# How to find out who shot a projectile

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

So I am trying to make a multiplayer game with abilities sort of like Overwatch/Paladins. All in all, one ability should be a sort of projectile that moves across the ground and allows that player to teleport to its position at any time while it is alive. I can't find the solution to teleporting only the player that shot it since thus far in my tests, when one player activated their ability, all players would teleport. How can I solve this?

My code:

```cs
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            GetComponent<playerController>().heldAbility = "gateCrash";

        if (GetComponent<playerController>().heldAbility == "gateCrash")
            holding = true;
        else
            holding = false;

        if (holding && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs", "GateCrashModel"), spawnPos, transform.rotation, 0);
    }
```

This code is attached to the projectile:

```cs
    public float speed = 10;

    PhotonView pv;

    private void Awake()
    {
        pv = transform.GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.Translate(transform.forward * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
```

I guess that I should make have something as instatntiation parameter but idk what.

Comment: You should give us more info about your workflow. You are just describing problem but depending on your workflow, there can be many ways to solve it. Unless, you edit and improve your question, your question probably will closed by mods. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to add a `shotOwner` property to each of your projectiles. Every time a projectile is fired, update `shotOwner` to point to the player object that fired the shot. (This will also let you implement "Player_X killed Player_Y" functionality, among other things.)